# Python Selenium: How to Open a Webpage Already Logged In

Tags: python, google-chrome, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping, selenium-chromedriver

I know this has been asked before but I've gone through countless posts and still can't get to work.
I'm trying to open a webpage using my existing chrome profile/user data in order to avoid having to login. Ideally I'd like to do this in a new window that I can later close and not affect any other open Chrome pages.
Whatever I try opens a new window that is not logged into Chrome nor the website.
Please help!

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service

path = Service(r"C:/...chromedriver.exe") #path to chromedriver

options = webdriver.ChromeOptions() 
options.add_argument(r"--user-date-dir=C:/Users/*username*/AppData/Local/Google/Chrome/User Data")
options.add_argument(r"--profile-directory=*profilename*")
options.add_argument('--no-sandbox')
options.add_argument('--disable-gpu')
options.add_experimental_option('excludeSwitches', ['enable-logging'])

browser = webdriver.Chrome(service=path, options=options)
url = "https://..."
browser.get(url)
```

Comment: I would recommend using javascript and chrome extension instead of selenium.

Answer (score 0):

basically you have to use cookies for this to work like u know the pickle module it can help u store the data and like its session management search about this you will get many help online its very easy use the cookies whenever and how much ever u want it will work only until a period of time
like in the below code first we will take the cookies in a pickle file like this

```
from selenium import webdriver
import pickle
import time


def save_cookies(cookies, filename):
    with open(filename, 'wb') as f:
        pickle.dump(cookies, f)


def load_cookies(filename):
    with open(filename, 'rb') as f:
        cookies = pickle.load(f)
    return cookies


url = "https://example.com"
driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get(url)
username_input = driver.find_element('xpath','username')
password_input = driver.find_element('xpath','password')

username_input.send_keys('your_username')
password_input.send_keys('your_password')

login_button = driver.find_element('xpath', 'login_button')
login_button.click()
time.sleep(5)
save_cookies(driver.get_cookies(), 'cookies.pkl')
driver.quit()
```

after doing this we should have a file .pkl ok you should also know that it should be done very fast and or else sometime it wont work now use that pickle file log back into account without the creds only using cookies like this

```
driver_restored = webdriver.Chrome()
driver_restored.get(url)
cookies_restored = load_cookies('cookies.pkl')
for cookie in cookies_restored:
    driver_restored.add_cookie(cookie)
driver_restored.refresh()
driver_restored.quit()
```

and also if u want to bypass cloudflare and other captchas make sure to use undetected chrome driver

Answer (score 0):

You have to use cookies. Here is an example:

```
def coockies_load(driver):
    if os.path.exists('cookies.pkl'):
        with open('cookies.pkl', 'rb') as file:
            cookies = pickle.load(file)
            for cookie in cookies:
                driver.add_cookie(cookie)
            print('Cookies loaded')
            time.sleep(5)
            driver.refresh()
            time.sleep(5)
    else:
        with open('cookies.pkl', 'wb') as file:
            pickle.dump(driver.get_cookies(), file)
        print('Save cookies')
        time.sleep(5)
```

Comment: This is a duplicate of [Furjack gaming's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/78105495/1519716), but with no explanation.